# Set JSChart visible x-axis

Tags: jscharts

Is there a way to set the visible x-axis range in JSChart despite the range of the data set?

I use JSChart to draw a line chart. The x-axis is date. The y-axis is an integer value (from 0 to 100).
Let's save x-axis min value is 2000-1-1 and max value is 2010-12-31).
Is there way way to configure JSChart to show only the part of data say (2005-1-1 to 2006-1-1)?

I have tried doing

```
config.data = myData
config.options.scales.x.suggestedMin = start
config.options.scales.x.suggestedMax = end
```

where start is `2005-1-1` and end is `2006-1-1`. But JSChart still show my data from the beginning, i.e. 2000-1-1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [this ref](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/):

`suggestedMin`  only change the data values that are used to **scale** the axis.

To change the **explicit** ends of the axis, use `min` and `max`.